# How to know all errors in Optimization process?

Tags: matlab, numerical-optimization

I am using fminsearch in MATLAB to iteratively find the answer of a function.
But it seems like the fminsearch cannot fulfill my expectation.
So I ask this question whether there is any way to do what I want.

According to MATLAB help, fminsearch finds the minimum of a scalar function of several variables, starting at an initial  estimate. So, if I am correct, I think this command finds an answer of the function at which the error of the iteration is minimum.

However, what I want to do is the same iteration process but the output I want is not an answer of the function at which the error is minimum. I want to know all errors in that iteration process (not an answer of the function).

Is there any way to do this task? I have tried so hard but I am a new bee and Mathematics is not my major. Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to know the value of the cost function for all iterations? If so, then you'll have to print/save it from within the cost function itself.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. But, does MATLAB allow me to print/save within the function?

Comment: Yes. Just put a `printf()` at the end of your cost value function.

Comment: Sorry, that should be `fprintf()`.

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of providing an answer, the functions in the Optimisation Toolbox have an option called `Display`. Setting the `Display` option to `iter` will show information from the optimisation function at each iteration.